# Spring MVC: Predefined exception classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In JAX-RS I have several exceptions extending `WebApplicationException`, for example `NotAuthorizedException` and `NotFoundException`. These are mapped to the corresponding HTTP status codes, so for basic use cases I can just throw instances of these exceptions.

In Spring MVC I noticed that I have to write my own exception classes, and add the corresponding `@ResponseStatus` annotations:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
private class NotAuthorizedException extends RuntimeException {
    NotAuthorizedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way? Do pre-defined exception classes exist?